# Question about SQL triggers

Tags: sql, triggers

Say there are two relations r and s such that the foreign key B of r references the primary key A of s.  How can the trigger mechanism be used to implement the **on delete cascade** option, when a tuple is deleted from s.

Comment: homework? Who in the real world talks like that? I have only seen academic questions phrased like this :-)

Comment: heh, kind of. studying for a final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER
  AFTER DELETE ON s
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM r WHERE r.B = old.A;
END;
```

This creates a trigger that run on each row deleted from s.
The trigger deletes the corresponding records from r, given the foreign key relationship you indicated.